# Receiving country name from region code

Tags: swift, locale, foundation

I have an array of country codes like: `["US","CZ","FR"]` etc. and I'd like to get localized country name iterating through this array.

Previously `localizedString(forRegionCode:)` worked perfectly. But probably since 10.3 something has changed.

Here's an example:

```
let currentLocale = Locale.current
// en_US (current)
let currentIdentifier = Locale.current.identifier
// "en_US"
let localeFromCurrentIdentifier = Locale(identifier: currentIdentifier)
// "en_US" (fixed)

let franceCode = "fr"

let franceName = currentLocale.localizedString(forRegionCode: franceCode)
// nil
let franceName2 = localeFromCurrentIdentifier.localizedString(forRegionCode: franceCode)
// "France"
```

So why current locale returns `nil` for France code and the locale initialized from current locale's identifier returns `France`?

**Update:** So the workaround to make `localizedString(forRegionCode:)` work is not to use `Locale.current`, but `Locale(identifier: Locale.current.identifier)`.

Comment: Both versions work for me in the 10.3 simulator under Xcode 8.3.1

Comment: Might be a playground issue.

Comment: @ChrisAllwein interesting, my app is not working properly if I use just `current` instead of initializing separate locale :/

Comment: Ah, good catch @rmaddy, I loaded this up in a playground and am seeing the nil result form Locale.current.localizedString.  So works on device and simulator, but not in playgrounds.  Time to file a Radar?

Comment: I tried with empty project and running on 10.3 simulator - same issue though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to maintain a table mapping each country code to a default language code, such as [this table](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim/Country_Codes) on Wikipedia. Pick a default language for each contry, as it may have multiple official languages, or even variations of the same language (Simplified vs. Traditional Chinese).

```
let countryCodes = ["US","CZ","FR"]

// Ideally, this should come from a plist
let defaultLanguageCodes = [
    "US": "en",
    "CZ": "cs",
    "FR": "fr"
]

let countryNames : [String] = countryCodes.map {
    let languageCode = defaultLanguageCodes[$0]!
    let localeIdentifier = "\(languageCode)_\($0.lowercased())"
    let locale = Locale(identifier: localeIdentifier)

    return locale.localizedString(forRegionCode: $0)!
}

print(countryNames) // United States, Česká republika, France
```